# How to rig a character where every element is separated?

Tags: rigging

I made a character where every element is separated as their own objects. (clothes, hair, eyes, tongue teeth, hands...) Should I join them to be one big mesh or keep them separated? How do I rig this and make weight paintings? I think automatic weights do not work probably. I have experiences that with autoweights I get for example jacket buttons behave in a weird way. Also, my knowledge of riggin is something in  these lines "Parent your object to bones with automatic weights and fix with weight paint". After that when I am able to pose my charcter with a very basic ways, I am thinking that the rig is "good enough".

[image: character]

Answer (score 1):

You can for example parent any mesh object to bones with 'Empty groups' option and then in weight paint mode paint the weights for that empty vertex group

Comment: Thanks. I found one cool addon which I hope would be able to do that weighting part automatically so that I won't need to use too much time with painting. Still not tested it but at least now I have some hope: https://blendermarket.com/products/voxel-heat-diffuse-skinning